# Is there a name for a programming structure where your code will look like a sentence?

Tags: coding-style, computer-science

I'm looking for the name of the technique about how to make code look like a sentence.

**Example:**

In many Test-Frameworks, you can just program tests like this (pseudo code):

```
expect(myObject.someNumber).toBeGreaterThan(4).toBeLessThan(7).toBeNotNull();
```

How is this principle called? Is there a pattern for this? Thank you!

Comment: Fluent. Kinda off topic, the guessing game...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was provided by user "Will" and is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve here it resembles some sort of [Design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) test pattern which it's not bad but if your end goal is to achieve live understandable documentation from your tests you should try some [BDD](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/) which provides a natural language to define your test cases that it's menat to be understood by anyone.